# template function in "Eclipse IDE" doesn't compile

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio-2010, templates

I have such function :

```
template<template <class _Ty, class _A = allocator<_Ty> > class Container>
    static void FreeAttributesVS(const Container<int>& arra)
    {
        for(Container<int>::const_iterator iter = arra.begin();
            iter != arra.end(); ++iter)
        {
            //do smthng
        }
    }
```

It compiles in VisualStudio but in Eclipse compiler says `"Invalid template argumetns"`, what should I do?

Comment: For what line does it say that?

Comment: 1st line when I hover mouse above `allocator<_Ty>` , it also says "Type _Ty could not be resolved"

Comment: So it is not really compiler that says it but intellisense (or whatever it is called in eclipse)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `typename` before `Container<int>::const_iterator` since that is a dependent type:

```
static void FreeAttributesVS(const Container<int>& arra)
{
    for (typename Container<int>::const_iterator iter = arra.begin(); ...)
    //   ^^^^^^^

}
```

Comment: It isn't actually a dependent type here, because the template parameter is known (`int`).

Comment: @juanchopanza But `Container` is a template argument.